# What could be the reason that my forecast using Prophet or Neural prophet doesn't capture the variability in my profile?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have data with 1 min resolution for almost 1 and half years, I am trying to predict 2 days ahead. As you can see in the picture Prophet and neural prophet (which is based on nonlinear regression supervised ML) is not capturing the variability within the profile. Even with Neural prophet, which is based on deep learning, I am getting similar results. Any ideas on how to customize/ tune these tools to capture some variability? I tried the changing points, but it didn't yield any good of results. [image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about DL theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info

Comment: I understand your point, but my question is what arguments I could pass to Prophet or Neural prophet in python to see the variability. For example: model = Prophet(interval_width=0.95, weekly_seasonality=True, daily_seasonality=True, yearly_seasonality=True)  --
model.add_country_holidays(country_name='USA')   --
model.fit()

Comment: Is there any other arguments or anything I could add to my code to capture variability in the profile?

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about: what arguments to pass in order to have better performance is not a *programming* question - it is about ML theory and methodology!

Comment: I get your point, maybe I presented the question in a generic way, sorry about that. But, I know ML very well, it's just I am not familiar with Prophet and Neural prophet. I know that the code has a lot of arguments that u could pass to prophet or neural prophet, but which one of them has more effect on the small fluctuations and could help improve the prediction?